# react: show a Highcharts map with geo points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

Please tell me how to indicate geo-points (i.e. objects with latitude and longitude) on the map.

I use React and HighchartsReact. I created this code:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import * as HighchartsMap from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

//import mapDataWorld from 'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.geo.json';
import mapDataWorld from '../jsons/maps/world.json';

const options: HighchartsMap.Options = {        
            title: undefined,
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'map',
                mapData: mapDataWorld,
                name: 'Great Britain',
                borderColor: '#a0a0a0',
                nullColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
                showInLegend: false
            }, {
                type: 'mappoint',
                name: 'Cities',
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{point.id}'
                },
                data: [{
                    id: 'London',
                    lat: 51.507222,
                    lon: -0.1275
                }, {
                    id: 'Birmingham',
                    lat: 52.483056,
                    lon: -1.893611
                }]
            }]
        };

        return (
<div className="mymap">
    <HighchartsReact
        options = {options}
        highcharts = {HighchartsMap}
        constructorType = {'mapChart'}
    />
</div>);
```

But the geo-point (London) is not correctly displayed on the map (ie just set to the coordinate (0,0), rather than the correct location on the map)

[image]

Please tell me what the error may be and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of using `geoJSON`you need to also inlcude `proj4js` library.

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-bb8f8z

However, currently there is an issue related to the `proj4js` using.
See the following threads to get an information about possible workarounds.

**Related threads:**
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17192
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=48802